# Valor de Input a un Array

Tags: javascript

Tengo un input llenado por un `foreach` (varios valores):

```
@foreach($detalles as $det)
                    <tr>            
                        <input type="hidden" name="id_detalle[]" value="{{ $det->id_detalle }}">
                        <td><input style=" width : 60px; border: none " type="number" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad[]" value="{{ $det->cantidad }}"></td>
                        <td><input style=" width : 600px; border: none " type="text" readonly name="descripcion[]" id="descripcion[]" value="{{ $det->descripcion }}"></td>
                        <td><input style=" width : 90px; border: none " type="number" step="0.01" name="v_unitario[]" id="v_unitario" value="{{ $det->v_unitario }}"></td>
                        <td><input style=" width : 90px; border: none " type="number" readonly id="v_parcial" name="v_parcial[]" value="{{ $det->v_parcial }}"></td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
```

Cómo puedo pasar los valores de input `id="cantidad[]"` a un array en javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes aprovechar que todos tienen el mismo nombre y con todos los que coinciden, recorres el arreglo y vas almacenándolo en un array

```
<script>
    //Obtengo todos los campos con el nombre cantidad[]
    var cantidad = document.getElementsByName("cantidad[]");
    //Creo el arreglo donde almaceno sus valores
    var arreglo = [];
    //Recorro todos los nodos que encontré que coinciden con ese nombre
    for(var i=0;i<cantidad.length;i++){
        //Añado el valor que contienen los campos
        arreglo.push(cantidad[i].value);
    }
    console.log(arreglo);
</script>
```

Comment: Listo me funciono pero tengo otra pregunta y es como almacenar los valores de un array para el input name="v_parcial[]" ya que hice esto parc[i] = cant[i]*unit[i]; y lo que me da en este parc[i] deseo poner en el input

Comment: Amigo si mi respuesta te funcionó aceptala como la indicada y lo segundo agregalo como una nueva pregunta. No obstante te voy a responder primero obtienes todos los campos con ese nombre como lo hice en la respuesta y en el for donde haces el calculo le asignas el valor calculado parcial[i].value = parc[i];